# Erro de parsing

Tags: java

Escrevi o código abaixo:

```
import java.lang.Math;

import.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        int y;
        int cont;
        int i;
        Scanner x = new.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite um número");
        y = x.Scanner();

        for(i = 1 to y) {

            if (y%i == 1){

                cont++;

            } 

            if (y%i == 2){

                cont++;

            }

        }   else{

                System.out.print("O número "+i+" nao e primo");             

                }
    System.out.print(cont)


  }
}
```

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo para contar a quantidade de números primos entre i e o que o usuário digitar. Alguma sugestão de um algoritmo melhor? Deu erro de parsing...

Comment: O que está tentando fazer com isso aqui `y = x.Scanner();`?

Comment: Escrevi errado --' kk deveria ser y = x.nextInt();

Comment: Isso não vai compilar, esse for está com sintaxe errada

Comment: e como poderia corrigi-lo?

Answer (score -1):

A sintaxe do for está errada. Você deveria fazer:

```
for(i = 1; i <= y; i++)
```

Comment: Acho que deveria tirar o int y e colocar int x; Scanner ler = new Scanner(); x = ler.nextInt();